# Why does from_json fail with "not found : value from_json"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jsonparser

I am reading a Kafka topic using Spark 2.1.1 (kafka 0.10+) and the payload is a JSON string. I'd like to parse the string with a schema and move forward with business logic.

Everyone seems to suggest that I should use `from_json` to parse the JSON strings, however, it doesn't seem to compile for my situation. The error being

```
not found : value from_json 
.select(from_json($"json", txnSchema) as "data")
```

When i tried the following lines into spark shell, it works just fine -

```
val df = stream
  .select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
  .select(from_json($"json", txnSchema) as "data")
  .select("data.*")
```

Any idea, what could I be doing wrong in the code to see this piece working in shell but not in IDE/compile time?

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Kafka10Cons3 extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName(Util.getProperty("AppName"))
    .master(Util.getProperty("spark.master"))
    .getOrCreate

  val stream = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", Util.getProperty("kafka10.broker"))
    .option("subscribe", src_topic)
    .load

  val txnSchema = Util.getTxnStructure
  val df = stream
    .select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
    .select(from_json($"json", txnSchema) as "data")
    .select("data.*")
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you're probably just missing the relevant import - `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`.

You have imported `spark.implicits._` and `org.apache.spark.sql._`, but none of these would import the individual function in `functions`.

---

> I was also importing `com.wizzardo.tools.json` which looks like it also has a `from_json` function, which must have been the one the compiler chose (since it was imported first?) and which was apparently incompatible with my version of spark

Make sure you are not importing the `from_json` function from some other json library, as this library may be incompatible with the version of spark you are using.

Comment: No, I'm using Spark 2.1.1 and this import works. The only thing I can think of is you might somehow have two different versions in your classpath, and the one picked up by compiler is too old.