# Why does from_json fail with “not found : value from_json"? (2)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Have already read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077644/why-does-from-json-fail-with-not-found-value-from-json) that is on SO.  None of those fixes are my problem.

I am unable to call the function "from_json".

I already had below in my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

I also tried adding:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

I am running Scala/Spark through Eclipse.  Scala Version 2.11.11, Spark Version 2.0.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from_json` function isn't available in [Spark 2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

It is available from [Spark 2.1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)

[Release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-1-0.html#core-and-spark-sql) of spark 2.1 mentions about adding `from_json` functionality

Comment: Can you see if the will add it to 2.0 for me?  Kidding.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can try building the source by adding the code :)